# Combining three sets of data in R

Tags: r, merge, r-table

I have made two table with the following code:

```
load(url("http://bit.ly/dasi_gss_data"))
pres<-table(gss$year,gss$confed)
emp<-table(gss$year,gss$joblose)
```

I am trying to now combine these two tables and keep all rows and columns in which the year is greater than 1987.  I have tried the merge function, but keep getting an error. Any suggestions? I would like to keep all the columns from the two tables grouped as they are by year. Thank you!

Comment: For future users, it would be useful to at least grab the first couple of rows of this data frame for the purposes of replication.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

gss %>%
  group_by(year, confed, joblose) %>%
  summarize(n = n())
```

Answer (score 0):

eventually first do

```
df.pres <- as.data.frame(unclass(pres))
df.emp <- as.data.frame(unclass(emp))
```

and then rename columns, merge() and subset()